# How to get index (or value) of DropDownButton selection

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a DownDownButton that I've populated from an array containing project names and ids. The list shows the project name, but I'd like to get the project id. The variable "projects" looks like this:

> [Object { name="Project A", id="1325"}, Object { name="Project B", id="5241"}, Object { name="Project C", id="3224"}]

This code creates the MenuItem for the button correctly, but how do I set the variable projId in the onClick event?

```
for (i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
    menuProjects.addChild(new MenuItem({
        label: projects[i].name,
        onClick: function () {
            projId = ?;
        }
   }));
}
```

I've tried using "projId= projects[i].id;", but that gives me an error since i is now 3. What's the correct syntax to do this?

**-- Edit --**

This is how I got it to work using both cookie's and Merrick's answers.

```
for (i = 0; i < projects.length; i++)
    (function (x) {
        menuProjects.addChild(new MenuItem({
            label: projects[i].name,
            onClick: function () {
                projId = projects[x].id;
            }
        }));
    } (i));
```

Comment: Why don't you just set `projId` before the function and if the scope doesn't let you access it, pass it in as a parameter? That way you havent iterated when you store the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the correct/best way to do it, but you could create a closure to give each iteration a new variable scope like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
    (function(x) {
        menuProjects.addChild(new MenuItem({
            label: projects[i].name,
            onClick: function () {
                projId = x;
            }
       }));
    }(i));

}
```

This creates an anonymous function (with its own scope) that is immediatly evaluated.

Comment: Awesome, very similar to my answer... You don't need the block though... JavaScript will do just find with the IIFE.

Comment: @MerrickChristensen What block is not needed? Or, actually - what is considered a block?

Comment: Your code can be rewritten as...

for (i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) (function(x) {
        menuProjects.addChild(new MenuItem({
            label: projects[i].name,
            onClick: function () {
                projId = x;
            }
       }));
    }(i));

Comment: This was close. I've edited the question to show how I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Since, the onClick callback is async and javascript is functionally scoped i will be hoisted and by the time the click event happens i will be the last value of i. To maintain the scope you can simply leverage a IIFE to properly scope i.

```
// Block scoping will all lazily evaluate to 10
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 100);
}


// Block scoping will capture the current value for each function invocation
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) (function(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 100);
})(i)
```

Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/eyeqiy/1/edit